# 12.04: php5-curl not working, NOT a LAMP server

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php

I've just setup a fresh install of 12.04 Server. Have everything working nicely, except getting this **php5-curl** mod to work.

I ran `apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl`

So I go check `phpinfo();` and there's no curl section.

Answer (score 1):

I heard I have to include a line in my `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` file, so I included:

`extension=php_curl.so`

and now it's working.